# Uso de callbackHandlers y re-validación de credenciales

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy haciendo(modificando un login en el cual hacen uso spring security, hacían uso de LDAP y ahí validaban que existiera un cliente y sus credenciales fueran correctas, ahora se esta cambiando por el consumo de servicios, el problema radica que el uso de spring security realiza una segunda validación para estar completamente seguro que es el cliente que dice ser, hay alguna forma de que solo se ejecute una única vez o llevar algo en sesión que me indique que ya fue validado?

Ya intente subir a sesión una clase de contador, pero no funciona.

Clases que estoy ocupando de spring para realizar el login:

CustomAuthenticationFilter
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
Authentication

Espero poder darme a entender.

Edit.

Realice un cast para agregar datos adicionales a el objeto authentication:

```
java.util.HashMap<String, String> map = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("FIRST_INTENT", "FIRST_INTENT");
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentications = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
            authentications.setDetails(map);
```

Ahora bien cuando quiera ejecutarse una segunda vez obtendré el valor del map y veré si ya se ejecuto por primera vez.

Es algo parecido a [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287667/how-to-store-custom-information-in-securitycontext-of-spring-security).

Gracias.

Comment: Cuando te refieres a que "...se está cambiando por el uso de servicios...", que quieres decir, que están haciendo una especie de API de servicios??

Comment: Se está migrando, la consulta de las credenciales de un cliente va pasar de LDAP a consumo de servicios

Comment: Si solo estás cambiando el modo de comprobar las credenciales del usuario que problemas tienes en que el resto del mecanismo de seguridad se mantenga igual?? Por lo que entiendo tienes el mismo mecanismo de autenticación, pero ahora en vez de validar credenciales contra LDAP lo haces contra un servicio.

Comment: Si es el mismo mecanismo, pero dentro de los servicios que consumo, solo puedo consumir una vez por cliente ese servicio, por que generó un tipo token que es válido solo para la sesión que está haciendo el cliente, y con el uso de callbackhandlers se realiza una segunda vez el consumo de los servicios, ya intenté quitarlos y nada, no sé si hay una configuración que me permita solo ejecutar una sola vez la validación de credenciales.

Comment: Los datos de autenticación en Spring Security se mantienen mientras no termine la sesión del usuario, y por lo tanto no tendrías que repetir la llamada al nuevo servicio de validación de credenciales durante la misma sesión. Ahora bien, todo depende del tipo de sistema que tengas (me refiero al principal, desde donde llamas al nuevo servicio que reemplaza al LDAP), ya que si dicho sistema no maneja sesiones, por ejemplo en el caso de un API REST, que debe ser stateless, no tienes modo de evitar llamar al servicio de validación de credenciales con cada request del usuario a tu sistema

Comment: Una solución es que en tu sistema utilices autenticación basada en JWT, con lo que podrías generarle un token a cada usuario e incluir dentro de este información adicional, como el token que genera el servicio de validación de credenciales. Pero como te decía, todo depende del diseño de tu sistema.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar los datos de mi pregunta @E.Betanzos

Comment: Eso solo te servirá si mantienes la sesión del usuario. Pero te digo más, el simple hecho de que el usuario ya esté autenticado es sinónimo de que se validaron sus credenciales correctamente en el servicio. Prueba así, pero estoy casi seguro que vas a tener los mismo resultados.